Redis aa cache manager in django project
What is the difference between using redis as pip install redis in your django project and keeping redis as a separate instance in another server? Will using redis in a project incur additional costs if I am using in as a package in my ec2 instance.

pip install redis is simply a command to install the Redis client, not the Redis server itself. If you're concerned about costs, a good approach would be to run the Redis server on the same instance where your Django application is hosted.
